# Serializing POJOs to/from JSON using jersey: weird nesting of elements

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I got the following structure of my classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="rootClass")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class rootClass {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="children")
    @XmlElement(name="child", type=childClass.class)
    private List<childClass> children;

    // Constructor, Getters, Setters    
}

public class childClass {
    private String name;
}
```

If instances are bound to xml, it looks like this, totally as expeced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rootClass>
    <children>
        <child>
            <name>Peter</name>
        </child>
        <child>
            <name>Griffin</name>
        </child>
    </children>
</rootClass>
```

But in JSON it looks like this:

```
{
    "children": {
        "child": [
            {
                "name": "Peter"
            },
            {
                "name": "Griffin"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

While i expect it to look like this:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Peter"
        },
        {
            "name": "Griffin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this behaviour caused by false annotations or result of missing annotations parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is how you can get this behaviour using MOXy as your JSON-binding provider by leveraging the `wrapperAsArrayName` property:

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class MyApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1);
        set.add(MyService.class);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();
        moxyJsonProvider.setWrapperAsArrayName(true);

        HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(1);
        set.add(moxyJsonProvider);
        return set;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/binding-to-json-xml-handling-collections.html